# How to map more than one table to a class with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy and am trying to map several tables to a class.

The tables are constructed like so:

```
Types
  -typeID
  -typeName
  -groupID
  ...

TypeAttributes
  -typeID
  -attributeID
  -attributeValueInt
  -attributeValueFloat
```

The idea is to have sqlalchemy map a from TypeAttributes to normal class attributes. 
As added complexity attributeValueInt and attributeValueFloat are exclusive. By which I mean each attributeID will have either an int or a float assossiated and the other will be null.

Any ideas how this could be done? or advice on a better way to do it (I have no control over the Database itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [How to map one class against multiple tables with SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300433/how-to-map-one-class-against-multiple-tables-with-sqlalchemy)