# Association objects with history for relationships using ORM

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

A common type of relationship in schemas is this: a joiner table has a datetime element and is meant to store history about relationships between the rows of two other tables over time. These relationships are one-to-one or one-to-many even though we're using an association table which usually implies many-to-many. At any given point in time only one mapping, the latest at that point in time, is valid. For example:

```
Tables: 
    Computer: [id, name, description]
    Locations: [id, name, address]
    ComputerLocations: [id, computers_id, locations_id, timestamp]
```

A `Computers` object can only belong to one `Locations` object at a time (and `Locations` can have many `Computers`), but we store the history in the table. Rows in `ComputerLocations` aren't deleted, only superseded by new rows at query-time. Perhaps in the future some prune-type event will remove older rows as their usefulness is reduced.

What I'm looking do do is model this in SQLAlchemy, specifically in the ORM, so that a `Computers` class has the following properties:

1. A new Computer can be created without (independently of) a location (this makes sense because the location table is separate)
2. A new Location can be created without (independently of) a computer
3. If a Computer has a location it must be a member of Locations (foreign key constraint)
4. When updating an existing Computers object's location, a new row will be added to ComputerLocations with a datetime of NOW()
5. When creating a new `Computers` object with a location, a new row will be added to `ComputerLocations` with a datetime of NOW()
6. Everything should be atomic (i.e. fail if a new Computer is created but the row associating it to a location can't be created)

Is there a specific design pattern or a concrete method in SQLAlchemy ORM to accomplish this? The documentation has a section on [Non-traditional mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html) that includes mapping a class against multiple tables and to arbitrary selects so this looks promising. Further there was another question of stackoverflow that mentioned [vertical tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300433). Due to my relative inexperience with SQLAlchemy I cannot synthesize this information into a robust and elegant solution yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using MySQL but a solution should be general enough for any database through the SQLAlchemy dialects system.